# Suggest a way to store the value form csv into dropdown with javascript variable perform operations on it

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script> //script loading the csv and reading the files to out into an array of variables which are used in dropdown 
var $csvData = [],
$colNames = [];
function _ReadCSV($a) {
    var $f = $a.files[0];
    if($f) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = function($e) {
            div.innerHTML = 'The file can\'t be read! Error ' + $e.target.error.code;
        }
        reader.onload = function($e) {
            var $data = $e.target.result.split("\n");
            $colNames = $data[0].split(",");     //split to separate the column inside the csv
            $data.splice(0, 1);
            for(var $b = 0; $b < $data.length; $b++) {
                var $tmpJSON = {},
                    $colData = $data[$b].split(",");
                for(var $c = 0; $c < $colData.length; $c++) $tmpJSON[$colNames[$c]] = $colData[$c];
                $csvData.push($tmpJSON);
      document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Value: "+ $colData; //just to check the value
            }
            _CreateDropdown();
        }
        reader.readAsText($f);
    }
}

function _CreateDropdown() {
    var $tmpHTML = '<select onchange="_UpdateFields(this.value)">';
    for(var $a = 0; $a < $csvData.length; $a++) $tmpHTML += '<option value="' + $a + '">' + $csvData[$a][$colNames[0]] + '</option>';
    $tmpHTML += '</select>';
    document.getElementById("dropdown").innerHTML = $tmpHTML;
    _UpdateFields(0);
}
function _UpdateFields($a) {
    var $values = '';
    for(var $b = 0; $b < $colNames.length; $b++) {
        console.log($colNames[$b], $csvData[$a][$colNames[$b]]);
        if($csvData[$a][$colNames[$b]] != "") $values += $colNames[$b] + ': <input id="' + $colNames[$b] + '" name="' + $colNames[$b] + '" type="text" value="' + $csvData[$a][$colNames[$b]] + '" /><br />';
    }
    document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML = $values;

}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('fileBox').onchange = function(){ _ReadCSV(this); }
}
</script>
```

Currently I have two columns in csv and need to pick the value of one of the column item. Which is selected upon the dropdown selected by the user and then need to modify the value. The `$values` variable stores both the columns values.

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong with your code?

Comment: in this code i am unable to find the variable storing the values of my csv although I was able to find the column name of my csv.

Comment: So log your `$csvData`. It's multi-dimentional array. First key shows row second key shows column name, so `$csvData[0]['name-of-column']` will return value of that "cell"